# comparing value from database to a string getting error java.sql.SQLException : No values specified for parameter 1

Tags: java, mysql

I want to create a login page that only admin can log in.

My database :
- tb_users
user_id (PK)
password

-tb_userauth
user_id (FK)
objects_id (contain roles of the user such as admin and customer)

**this is my program:**

```
private void cmd_loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try{
        String sql = "select * from tb_users where user_id=? and password=?";           
        PST=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        PST.setString(1,txt_userid.getText());
        PST.setString(2, txt_pass.getText());
        RS=PST.executeQuery();
        RS.close();


        String sql2 = "select * from tb_userauth where objects_id=?";           
        PST=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
        RS=PST.executeQuery();
        String objek = "admin";
        String objek_id = RS.getString("objects_id");        

        if(RS.next()){

             if (objek.equals(objek_id)){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"user id and password correct");
             submenu1 sm1 = new submenu1();
             sm1.setVisible(true);
             sm1.pack();
             sm1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
             sm1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             this.dispose();
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"check your password and user id ");
        } }  

    }catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }


}
```

**and I got an error like this:**
java.sql.SQLException: No values specified for parameter 1

this is make me confused because i already use String objek_id = RS.getString("objects_id");

is there something wrong with my ResultSet?

Comment: You're not setting the parameter (`objects_id`) in your second query. What's not clear?

Comment: Is 'tb_users' table has 'objects_id' column

Comment: no it doesn't. tb_users is parent table. @janith1024

Comment: what do you mean by parameter? i use **String objek_id = RS.getString("objects_id");** to get value from my database then i compare it to **String objek = "admin";** @shmosel

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the parameter of the second prepared statement. I guess you did some mistake in query so I change the query  and commented in the changes. I didn't run and test so some issues could be there. You can have idea on this.

```
private void cmd_loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  try{
    String sql = "select * from tb_users where user_id=? and password=?";           
    PST=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    PST.setString(1,txt_userid.getText());
    PST.setString(2, txt_pass.getText());
    RS=PST.executeQuery();
    String user_id = RS.getString("user_id"); //I don't know the type of use_id so I guess it as string

    RS.close();


    String sql2 = "select * from tb_userauth where user_id=?"; //I change object_id to user_id   

    PST=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
    PST.setString(1,user_id);//this might not be string
    RS=PST.executeQuery();
    String objek = "admin";
    String objek_id = RS.getString("objects_id");        

    if(RS.next()){

         if (objek.equals(objek_id)){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"user id and password correct");
         submenu1 sm1 = new submenu1();
         sm1.setVisible(true);
         sm1.pack();
         sm1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         sm1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         this.dispose();
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"check your password and user id ");
    } 
  }  

  }catch (Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
  }


}
```

Comment: not only query other all comment at end of the line. then java.sql.SQLException: No values specified for parameter 1 exception should not happen.

Comment: there's some miscommunication here.. i'm using my second query to get values objects_id from database then compare it to 'admin'. if i change my second query into **String sql2 = "select * from tb_userauth where user_id=?";** as you suggest then i don't retieve any values from objects_id @janith1024

Comment: of course i'm not only change the query. i also change every statement that you put comment on.

Comment: Then simply remove where condition of second query

Comment: it works. but another error appeared **java.sql.sqlexception before start of result set** @janith1024

Comment: Revert my changes then remove where condition of your code

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it (english isn't my first langguage). Did you mean move this : **String objek = "admin";
    String objek_id = RS.getString("objects_id");** under **if(RS.next())** statement? (Where conditions already deleted).  I've done that and it' showing "check your password and user id ". Does that means it's still not retieve data from object_id and compare it to string 'admin'? By the way, thank you for your patience to anwers my questions. @janith1024